# How to file for FIPRTA tax withholding and can I request interest from IRS?

Tags: taxes, capital-gains-tax, irs

I sold my property in 2020 and prepaid FIPRTA tax withholding since I am a foreigner. Theoretically, the tax withholding is supposed to be refunded the same year during the tax season. However, IRS messed things up since they misplaced my payment. It took them three years to find it. And finally, I can apply for a refund this year. My question is

Which form(s) should I fill out to apply for the refund?
Can I request interest from IRS since it's their mistake that leads to a delayed refund? If so, how should I proceed?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> However, IRS messed things up since they misplaced my payment. It took them three years to find it. And finally, I can apply for a refund this year.

How's it your problem that the IRS messed something up? You should have filed the 1040NR with the withholding statement you got from the withholding agent for the year of the transaction.

You need to hurry up, the statute of limitations for 2020 will close this April.